# ExpandableListView with Multie View Types Crashing On Scroll etc

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview, android-query, aquery

For some reason my expandableListView is crashing on Scroll or rotation change. I have two View Types for this activity

Code:

```
    @Override
    public int getGroupType(int groupPosition){
        return comments.get(groupPosition).is_load_more;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupTypeCount(){
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,  View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;
        View vi = convertView;
        final commentItem item = getGroup(groupPosition);
        if(vi == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            if(getGroupType(groupPosition) == 1){
                vi = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_loadmore, null);
                holder.load_more = (Button)vi.findViewById(R.id.comments_load_more);
            }else{
                vi = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.comments_item, null);
                holder.aq = new AQuery(vi);
                holder.usericon = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comments_item_userpic);
                holder.username = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comments_item_username);
                holder.fullname = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comments_item_fullname);
                holder.content = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comments_item_content);
                holder.commentc = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comments_item_commentcount);
                holder.commentBtn = (FrameLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.comments_item_comment);
                holder.bumpBtn = (ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comments_item_bump);
                holder.bumpc = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.comments_item_countbump);
                holder.replyLayout = (LinearLayout)vi.findViewById(R.id.comments_item_replyLayout);
            }

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        if(getGroupType(groupPosition) == 1){

        }else{
            holder.aq.id(R.id.comments_item_userpic).image(item.user_img, true, false, 96, 0);
```

Logcat:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at test.com.CommentsActivity$commentAdapte
r.getGroupView(CommentsActivity.java:243)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getVie
w(ExpandableListConnector.java:446)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsList
View.java:2268)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListVi
ew.java:1790)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.jav
a:691)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.ListView.fillSpecific(ListView
.java:1349)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListVi
ew.java:1641)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListVi
ew.java:2117)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:
4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(Lin
earLayout.java:1671)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(Li
nearLayout.java:1525)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLa
yout.java:1434)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:
4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(Fra
meLayout.java:453)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayo
ut.java:388)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:
4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayL
ayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:
4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(Fra
meLayout.java:453)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayo
ut.java:388)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:
4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewR
ootImpl.java:1987)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(V
iewRootImpl.java:1744)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRoo
tImpl.java:1000)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.r
un(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run
(Choreographer.java:761)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreo
grapher.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreograp
her.java:544)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventR
eceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.jav
a:733)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.ja
va:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThrea
d.java:5081)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:5
15)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndA
rgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(Zygot
eInit.java:607)
E/AndroidRuntime( 9861):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Its crashing on "holder.aq.id(R.id.comments_item_userpic).image(item.user_img, true, false, 96, 0);" and I have no idea why. Could anyone help me?

Comment: "It is not guaranteed that the convertView will have been previously created by getGroupView(int, boolean, View, ViewGroup)." So if you're not setting the holder on getChildView you'll probably have a nullpointer.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to add 
                vi.setTag(holder);
after I setup the view holders for the first time. My bad :S hope this helps anyone having a similar issue